# Генератор подмножества словаря python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, словари

Функция `add_to_table(d)` вызывается каждую секунду с помощью:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

d={1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
timer2 = QTimer(self)
timer2.setInterval(1000)
timer2.timeout.connect(add_to_table(d))
timer2.start()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать, чтобы при первом вызове функция принимала бы  `d={1: 'a'}`, при втором `d={1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` и т.д.

Comment: ключ - чило от 1, значение - очередная буква алфавита? "и т.д." до каких пор?

Comment: да, именно так
до конца словаря

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте алфавит:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
```

или просто:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Поместите `add_to_table(d)` в цикл по `enumerate(letters, 1)` (от 1):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

d = dict()
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i, l in enumerate(letters, 1):
    d.update({i: l})

    timer2 = QTimer(self)
    timer2.setInterval(1000)
    timer2.timeout.connect(add_to_table(d))
    timer2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, \
    QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central_widget = QWidget(self)       
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
        self.d_keys = sorted(self.d.keys())
        self.d_len = len(self.d_keys)
        self.d_flag = 0
        
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start", clicked=self.onClick)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid.addWidget(self.label)        
        grid.addWidget(self.button) 

        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.add_to_table)
        
    def onClick(self):
        if not self.timer2.isActive():
            self.timer2.start()
            self.button.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.timer2.stop()
            self.button.setText("Start")

    def add_to_table(self):
        if self.d_flag < self.d_len:
            _d = {}
            for i in self.d_keys[0:self.d_flag+1]:
                if self.d.get(i):
                   _d[i] = self.d[i] 
            self.label.setText(f'dict = {str(_d)}')       
            print(_d)
            self.d_flag += 1
            
        else:
            self.timer2.stop()
            self.d_flag = 0
            self.button.setText("Start")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont.Bold))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(640, 480)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]